# New environment with variable number of items

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

this is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [name path=K] (-1.5,0) arc [start angle=180,end angle=0,radius=1.5cm];
  \foreach \x in {1,...,6} {
   \draw [name path=A] ({0.1*(6-\x},0) -- +({(1.5/6*(6-\x)},{(1.5/6*\x}) node [anchor=west] {Die ist Zeile \x.};
   \path [name intersections={of=K and A,by=KA}];
  }
  \foreach \x in {5,...,1} {
   \draw [name path=A] ({-0.1*(6-\x},0) -- +({-(1.5/6*(6-\x)},{(1.5/6*\x}) node [anchor=east] {Die ist Zeile \x.};
   \path [name intersections={of=K and A,by=KA}];
  }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

Now I want do make a new command/environment to automate this.

Let's say

```
\begin{labelgroup}(x-coord.,y-coord.){start-angle,end-angle}
 \label{Label 1}
 \label{Label 2}
 ....
\end{labelgroup}
```

The best way would be that the environment count the number of labels and calculate the correct values. If this is to difficult, it would be ok, if you have to give the number of labels as argument.

I have no idea how to start. How to count the labelcommands ...

Best regards

Comment: I think you should start with providing a full **MWE**.

Comment: What means MWE?

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: The overall problem is challenging, but I can help with reading your labels.  Try this code: `\usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\NewEnviron{rlabelgroup}[1]{%
  \ignoreemptyitems%
  \setsepchar{\label}
  \readlist\rightlg{\BODY}%
  label count: \listlen\rightlg[]\par
  labels:\par
  \foreachitem\x\in\rightlg[]{\x\par}
}` and then invoke it with `\begin{rlabelgroup}{blah}
\label First label
\label second label
\label third label
\end{rlabelgroup}`  If you change the `\readlist` to `\greadlist` (global) then individual labels can later be obtained with, for example, `\rightlg[2]`.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this gives you a general idea

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcount\numberoflabels
\newenvironment{labelgroup}{
    \numberoflabels=0
    \def\label##1{
        \advance\numberoflabels by1
        \pgfkeys{/my labels/\the\numberoflabels/.code={##1}}
    }
}{
    \tikz{
        \draw foreach\i in{1,...,\numberoflabels}{
            (0,0)--node[sloped,anchor=base]{\pgfkeys{/my labels/\i}}({180/\the\numberoflabels*(\i-.5)}:3)
        };
    }
}

\begin{labelgroup}
    \label{alice}
    \label{bob}
    \label{carol}
    \label{dave}
    \label{eve}
    \label{frank}
\end{labelgroup}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thanks for the code. I will have a closer look now.

Comment: I needed some minutes to understand the code in detail. Cool thing, thats a very good start! Thx.

Comment: I face the problem, that I can't add an argument to the environment.

Comment: If I change \newenvironment{labelgroup}{ to \newenvironment{labelgroup}[1]{ and the 180 to #1 and then \begin{labelgroup} to \begin{labelgroup}{180} I got a lot of errors.

Comment: @fatts: It seems to be an innate restriction that `#1` can only appear in the `\begin` part. That is, you need something like `\newenvironment{labelgroup}[1]{\def\rememberdegree{#1}}{use \rememberdegree}`.